# MySQL query on single table to find multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to figure out a way to find shared credits by two people in a movie database, for example:

table: 'credits'
columns: 'id','movie','person'

My other problem is a person might have multiple credits for the same movie, so how do I filter out duplicates? Any help would be appreciated. The following is what I have so far. Am I on the right track?

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie
FROM credits
WHERE person = 'condition1' OR person = 'condition2'
GROUP BY movie
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Comment: what output are you getting on execution of your query?

Comment: DISTINCT is redundant if you GROUP BY. About duplicates, Why don't you set a UNIQUE KEY on movie + person?

Comment: @Capsule Coz it's not unique by the OP's description :)

Comment: @Emmerman well, according to the table description (no other fields than id/movie/person), movie+person should be unique (i'm talking about one unique key on both columns at once, not 2 unique keys).

Comment: @Capsule I think there's more columns (something like `role` - editor, actor, producer etc)

Comment: @Emmerman sorry, I've lost my crystal ball last week ;-)

Comment: @Capsule It's obvious :) Real world a little bit more complicated than examples in SO ;)

Comment: You're correct, there are other columns, one being an actual 'credit' column that describes the role like you said-- 'Dr. Alan Grant' or 'director','editor','raptor wrangler', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct cr1.movie
from credits as cr1
join credits as cr2
using (movie)
where cr1.person = {person 1 goes here}
and cr2.person = {person 2 goes here}
```

Comment: -1 won't work because you are joining on the unique id, giving an empty get, because a credit with the same id cannot have 2 people.

Comment: THANK YOU. This works great and seems to be the fastest solution. You rock my face off. I peed my pants just now. Literally.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.movie
FROM credits AS c1
JOIN credits AS c2 on (c1.movie = c2.movie)
WHERE c1.person = 'john'
AND c2.person = 'kate'
```

Comment: Speaking of speed ... moving the `WHERE` conditions to `JOIN` would be faster, but it's a correct answer, nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, this worked great but as Narf recommended the JOIN is faster like GordonM posted below. Didn't realize you could join a table on itself... newb ->

Comment: @Stephen you haven't timed it, it's an identical join.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie
FROM (
      SELECT movie, COUNT(person) AS contributors
      FROM credits
      WHERE person IN('person1','person2')
      GROUP BY movie, person
      HAVING contributors>1
     ) t1
```

Comment: -1 very slow query, `group by movie, person` should be `group by person` then `select distinct movie` can be just `select movie`. Of course the count will still make it slow.

Comment: `GROUP BY person` would give incorrect results when there's a person that has two contributions to the same movie. It might be slow for a table that has millions of rows, but I never said it was fast and you're just trying to find an excuse to give negative votes for everybody that's trying to help(except for yourself of course ...), which is pure trolling.

Comment: looking at the answers, I see your point. Speed was indeed not a requirement, and your answer does give the correct result.

Comment: @Johan, I don't really care about the votes, a single one won't ruin my "reputation" or anything. I never tested it anyways ... so it might not be correct too. I just wanted to make my point and since you get it ... it's fine by me.

Answer (score -1):

You no need this `HAVING COUNT(*)=2`. It gives you only movies with two matches (one person with two credits or with both `condition1` and `condition2`). More than that - you no need `group by` at all when you using `distinct` (in this case).

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie
FROM credits
WHERE person = 'condition1' OR person = 'condition2'
```

Comment: @Johan Agreed. Miss `shared` in question (still not good with english)